# Extract new field url_address from log body

Tags: splunk, splunk-formula

I would like to extract using a regex splunk the value of `~Address: :`  from the below log body

```json
{"severity":"DEBUG","logger":"com.api.test.api.LogFilter","thread":"http-nio-8084-exec-2","message":"2023-02-01 20:01:06  [http-nio-8084-exec-2] DEBUG c.a.p.utils.api.filter.LogFilter  - ~APP: API-Parametrage\r\n~Uuid: 6b7639f9-4e3c-491f-b3dd-ded494244f2a\r\n\r\nREQUEST **********************************\r\n~Address: : blablahost:80\/api\/cars\/bmw\/g\/v1\r\n~Encoding: UTF-8\r\n~Http-Method: POST\r\n~Content-Type: application\/json;charset=UTF-8\r\n}
```

my expected result is : `http://blablahost:80/api/cars/bmw/g/v1`

I have used this regex but dosen't work for me : `Address: (.*?(?:(?!Encoding).)*)`

How can I select up until the line break just before the `\r\n~Encoding:`?

Many thanks.

Tried : `Address: (.*?(?:(?!Encoding).)*)`

Expected : `http://blablahost:80/api/cars/bmw/g/v1`

Answer (score 0):

This regex will take everything from the second `:` following "Address" until the "\r".  It assumes the "\r" are two literal characters rather than a carriage return.

`Address: : (?<URL>.*?)\\r`

If the `\r` is really a line ender then this regex is more efficient.

`Address: : (?<URL>\S+)`

Comment: thanks for your answer , that selected what I need but it still have the "/\" in the url.

Comment: it's selected like this : blablahost:80\/api\/cars\/bmw\/g\/v1

********
What I am need is : http://blablahost:80/api/cars/bmw/g/v1

Comment: You can use the `rex` command in `sed` mode to fix that at search time.  `| rex field=URL mode=sed "s/\\\//g"`.